# email sending on php form registration

Tags: php

Can't seem to get thhis script work. Although registration part works fine and data gets inserted but shows error in result page:

```
Not found your email in our databaseCannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address
```

Code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con) { die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());}
$db_select=mysqli_select_db($con, "");
if (!$db_select) { die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());}

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);
$password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass1']);
$password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass2']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['phone']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email1']);
if(isset($_POST['country'])){ $country = $_POST['country'];}
if(isset($_POST['state'])){ $state = $_POST['state'];}
// Random confirmation code
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand())); 

/* Data Insertion & PASSWORD 1 = 2 CHECK */
if($password1==$password2 && !empty($username) && !empty($name) && !empty($phone) && !empty($email) && !empty($country) && !empty($state)){ /* IF PASSWORD1 IS THE SAME WITH PASSWORD2 */
/* INSERT QUERY */    
$query = "INSERT INTO temp_users (confirm_code,username,password,name,phone,email,country,state) VALUES ('$confirm_code','$username','$password1','$name','$phone','$email','".$country."','".$state."')";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
if ($result) {
$to = $email;
$subject = "Activate Vacation Rental Link";
// From
$header = "VacationByChoice <enquiry@craigburst.com>";
// message
$message = "Your Confirmation link \r\n";
$message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
$message.="https://craigburst.com/confirmation-link-validation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";
// send email
if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
} else {
echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";}
} else {
echo "Not found your email in our database";}}}
?>
```

Form:

```
Username:<input type="text" name="user" maxlength="20" class="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /><?php if (!empty($username) === false){echo '<font style="color:#FF0000">* Username</font>';
} else /* duplicate username Validation */ $check_user = ("SELECT username FROM temp_users WHERE username='$username'"); $run = mysqli_query($con,$check_user);
if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0) {
echo "<font style='color:#FF0000'>* User Exists</font>";} ?>

Choose Password:<input type="password" maxlength="20" name="pass1" value="<?php echo $password1; ?>" /><?php if (!empty($password1) === false){
echo '<font style="color:#FF0000">* Password</font>';} ?>

Repeat Password:<input type="password" maxlength="20" name="pass2" value="<?php echo $password2; ?>" /><?php if (!empty($password2) === false){
echo '<font style="color:#FF0000">* Password</font>';}
elseif($password1!=$password2) { echo '<font style="color:#FF0000">* No Match</font>';} ?>

Full Name:<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /><?php if (!empty($name) === false){
echo '<font style="color:#FF0000">* Name</font>';} ?>

Phone:<input type="text" maxlength="20" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" /><?php if (!empty($phone) === false){
echo '<font style="color:#FF0000">* Phone</font>';} ?>

Email:<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="email1" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /><?php if (!empty($email) === false){
echo '<font style="color:#FF0000">* Email</font>';}
elseif (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
echo '<font style="color:#FF0000">* email';} else
/* duplicate Entry Validation */
$check_email = "SELECT email FROM temp_users WHERE email='$email'";
$run = mysqli_query($con,$check_email);
if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0) {
echo "<font style='color:#FF0000'>* Email Exists</font><br/>";} ?>

Country:<select id="country" class="style" name="country">
<option>Select</option></select><?php if ($country=['select']){
echo '<font style="color:#FF0000">* Country</font>';} ?>

State/ Province:<select id="state" class="style" name="state"></select><?php if ($state=['select']){
echo '<font style="color:#FF0000">* State</font>';} ?>

<img src="captcha.php" alt="Captcha" /><input type="text" name="vercode" /><?php /* Captcha Validation */
if ($_POST['vercode']!=$_SESSION['vercode'] OR $_SESSION["vercode"]===''){
echo '<font style="color:#FF0000">* code</font>';} ?>

<input type="submit" name="register" value="Sign Up" />
```

Seeking help on this. Error reporting has been added already.

Comment: You're using `mysqli_query` twice.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` during development.

Comment: Remove `$result=mysqli_query($query);`, then replace `if($result){` with `if($query){`

Comment: King @Fred-ii- strikes again. And as stated you're trying to do `mysqli_query(mysqli_query("SQL QUERY IS IN HERE"))`, not good.

Comment: @Darren You're too kind ;-)

Comment: @Darren You're more than welcome to submit an answer, you have my blessing. I'm not touching this one; let's just say I'm not particularly fond of "cans of worms" ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try to refrain from these errors..

Comment: Looks good to me @Darren We'll just need to wait and see if OP knows "the ropes" around here and accepts it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- care to clarify issues here in answer comments?

Comment: @Fred-ii- read answers comments, OP still having issues with query apparently returning false

Comment: @Darren Sorry but I can't go over OP's code anymore. At this time of night too, my head's elsewhere.

Comment: @Fred-ii- affirmative, I don't want any babies now so play it safe ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my brother from another mother has suggested. You can try this.

Firstly set `error reports` on to help you debug this further.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

That should help you narrow down the cause of your errors.
Now on to your query. As you  can see, you're setting your query like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO temp_users (confirm_code,username,password,name,phone,email,country,state) VALUES ('$confirm_code','$username','$password1','$name','$phone','$email','$country','$state')");
$result=mysqli_query($query);
```

Which means, you're trying to run it like this: **`mysqli_query(mysqli_query('sql query in here'))`**. That won't work. Try setting it up like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO temp_users (confirm_code,username,password,name,phone,email,country,state) VALUES ('$confirm_code','$username','$password1','$name','$phone','$email','$country','$state')";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

You see how `$query` is the actual query string and `$result` runs the query through `mysqli_query()`.

And now keeping in scope, you should do something like this with your code blocks for better management:

```
if ($result) {
            $to = $email;
            $subject = "Avtivate Vacation Rental Link";
            // From
            $header = "VacationByChoice <enquiry@craigburst.com>";
            // message
            $message = "Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
            $message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
            $message.="https://craigburst.com/confirmation-link-validation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";
            // send email
            if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
                echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
            } else {
                echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Not found your email in our database";
        }
```

Notice how we removed the whole `$sentmail` and check `mail` directly with the if statement.

Does that help you out?

---

### Notes

Just a few side notes; you have a typo here:

```
$subject="Avtivate Vacation Rental Link";
```

should be

```
$subject="Activate Vacation Rental Link";
```

and

```
$message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
```

should be

```
$message="Your Confirmation link \r\n";
```

Just had to be picky or Fred will beat me:P

Comment: The page look far better after with this code and by resolving error by error reporting. Although link is still not bieng sent to email, error "Not found your email in our database".. However data inserts in db.

whole new script is added above in question. Thanks again

Comment: @user3674873 what happens when you change `$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);` to `$result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));` ?

Comment: Show no error but country & state area gets highlighted as if no input was selected.. thanks

Comment: @user3674873 you understand that with this line: `if ($country=['select'])` you are basically saying `$country` **equals (is)** an array with one value of `select`..

Comment: I will try to check by removing conditioning from country and state.. Basically I wanted it ti be compulsory and how I did was "select is default value so If is selected as 'Select' dont execute..

Comment: @user3674873 what happens if you try `if($country == 'select')` instead of what you have.

Comment: it doesnt work, even new errors shows up.. I even removed the conditioning for both options.. no data inserts and no error

Comment: That was my fault anyways here is the link..https://vacationsbychoice.com/owner_login.php

Comment: @user3674873 So the email isn't sending at all?

Comment: No.. I am new to php so not sure if I have to attach any additional file from my email server inorder to execute email function..